# How to create my own basemap in ArcGIS from JPEG files?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, tiles

I have my own *.jpg tiles. How to create basemap from it and publish as service via ArcGIS for server?
I was trying to find my issue in documentation, but I didn't have success. It seems very easy for usual ArcMAP users, but not for me.

Comment: *.jpg tiles, do you have thousands of these already created showing various scales of vector images?  Do these images have spatial reference?  What issue are you having?

Comment: I know how to map images to coordinates from MapInfo *.tab files (coordinates (122000, 94000) => image point (0, 0), etc. ). I need to create from *.tab and *.jpg files one layer and publish it in ArcGIS Server.

Comment: I have have thousands of these raster images in big scale.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the decision.

1. Convert all *.tab + *.jpg to *.ovr + *.aux + *.jpg.
   [image]
2. Add all converted files to map in ArcMap.
3. Share map as service.